# Convert class of a group of backticked columns using the tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I convert the class of a group of backticked columns using the tidyverse?

Here, the data frame `sumtbl` has lab test results for clinical trial patients Bill and Ted, and the class of the backticked columns is factor. I use the *tidyr* `spread` function to convert the lab results from long to wide. I use as.character in this example because in the real world, my results are numbers stored as character values.

```
set.seed(7073)
basetbl <- data.frame(pt  = c("BILL","TED"), 
                      res = as.character(abs(rnorm(10))),
                      day = rep(c(1:5), 2))

sumtbl  <- basetbl %>% 
           group_by(pt) %>%
           spread(key = day, value = res) %>%
           ungroup()
```

[image: basetbl data frame with random numbers for the res column]

Among my attempted solutions has been the creation of a character vector with the backticked column names, but then my use of `mutate_at` yields an evaluation error - object not found.

```
modcols  <-  sapply(seq(1:tail(colnames(sumtbl), 1)), function(x) paste0('`',x, '`'))
```

[image]

```
outtbl   <-  sumtbl %>%
             mutate_at(modcols, funs(as.numeric(.)))
```

[image]

I can change the columns directly but is there a better way?

```
sumtbl$`1` <- as.numeric(sumtbl$`1`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the `names` to select the columns

```
sumtbl %>%
     mutate_at(names(.)[-1],  funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#     pt       `1`       `2`        `3`       `4`       `5`
#  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   BILL 0.4861669 0.1039447 0.69618180 0.7344558 0.9792622
#2    TED 1.2097490 0.6166524 0.01480253 0.9925388 1.0973267
```

Note that the backquotes are showed only in the print output.  If we look at the `names`

```
names(sumtbl)[-1]
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

So, the 'modcols' would be

```
modcols <- names(sumtbl)[-1]
sumtbl %>%
     mutate_at(modcols,  funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#      pt       `1`       `2`        `3`       `4`       `5`
#   <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1   BILL 0.4861669 0.1039447 0.69618180 0.7344558 0.9792622
#2    TED 1.2097490 0.6166524 0.01480253 0.9925388 1.0973267
```

Wrapping with `vars` is not needed here

Comment: I had additional columns in the real world so I modified akrun's modcols statement to the following so I could capture only the enumerated (referenced via backticks) columns:

modcols  <-  names(sumtbl)[grepl("1|2|3|4|5", names(sumtbl))]

Answer (score 5):

The following will work. In addition, you are converting factor to numeric, so it is imperative to convert the factor to character first, and then numeric, using `as.numeric(as.character(.))`.

```
outtbl   <-  sumtbl %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-pt), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))

# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#       pt       `1`       `2`        `3`       `4`       `5`
#   <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1   BILL 0.4861669 0.1039447 0.69618180 0.7344558 0.9792622
# 2    TED 1.2097490 0.6166524 0.01480253 0.9925388 1.0973267
```